# SQL Server cancel rounding the result of multipication

Tags: sql-server, rounding

I'd appreciate if you could look into the following SQL code and tell me how to make SQL server NOT to round the result of the multipication of tje 4th select column:

```
    select  --tmp1.[Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned] CR,
            tmp2.cnt_match / cast(tmp1.cnt as float)   as precision,
            tmp1.cnt as cnt,
            tmp2.cnt_match / cast(tmp1.cnt as float) * tmp1.cnt


    from 
    ( select [Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned],COUNT(*) as cnt from 
    dbo.CEA_CR CEA_CR
    where CEA_CR.cycle = '4' and CEA_CR.version = '1'
    group by [Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned] )  as tmp1
    ,
    (select [Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned],COUNT(*) as cnt_match from 
    dbo.CEA_CR CEA_CR
    where  [Session.Did_Call_Type_happen_on_this_call]= 'Yes' and CEA_CR.cycle = '4' and CEA_CR.version = '1'
    group by [Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned])  tmp2
    where tmp1.[Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned] = tmp2.[Session.Call_TYPE_Assigned]
```

the result set look like this

0.666666666666667
3
2

while 2 is not the product of 0.6 * 3
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think either:

```
convert(float,tmp2.cnt_match / cast(tmp1.cnt as float) * tmp1.cnt)
```

as the last line of the select or

```
convert(float,[precision] * tmp1.cnt)
```

as the last line of the select might work.

Comment: I am a bit surprised because if you run SELECT convert(FLOAT,0.6667 * 2) on your machine you should get 2.0001!

Comment: Hey, I just ran 0.666666666666667 in the above select and it also gives 2, maybe this is accurate enough for SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe it's just float! SELECT convert(decimal(16,15),0.666666666666667  * 3).